# linq slow statement due to left join ? or group by

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Hi I have below linq query but it's very slow... i thin it's quite slow when it's doing left join... but can't really tell whether this is the case.

```
 var lastPayment = (from p in _context.CustomerPayment
                           group p by p.CustomerId into grps
                           select new
                           { PaymentID = grps.Max(x => x.PaymentId) });


        List<CustomerPaymentViewModel> data = await (from cp in _context.CustomerPayment
                                                     join lp in lastPayment
                                                     on cp.PaymentId equals lp.PaymentID into _l
                                                     from lp in _l.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                     orderby cp.PaymentId descending
                                                     select new CustomerPaymentViewModel()
                                                     {
                                                         CustomerName = cp.Customer.CustomerName,
                                                         PaymentAmount = ((decimal)cp.Payment.PaymentAmount).ToString("n0"),
                                                         PaymentDate = cp.Payment.PaymentDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                                         PaymentID = cp.Payment.PaymentId,
                                                         OutstandingAmount = cp.OutstandingAmount == null ? "" : ((decimal)cp.OutstandingAmount).ToString("n0"),
                                                         PaymentMethod = cp.Payment.PaymentMethod == null ? "" : cp.Payment.PaymentMethod,
                                                         Editable = lp != null ? "1" : "0"
                    }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Try moving the OrderBy until after the Select. That _might_ help, but your "very slow" is vague, and you'd need to check the generated SQL, and check to see how it performs in your database with measurements on different queries.

Comment: Tips: Check generated SQL and then check execution plan. Depending to your execution plan, you may want to add some indices to your table.

Comment: Okay. I am running the SQL profile to see the generated sql but it looks like all these group by and order by , left join is done at c# end after it selects all rows from the table.